# Which part of the plugin to change so the updater won't register the next version?

Tags: plugins, updates

I have made a change in WP qTip plugin so only a specific `a.something[title]` instead of `a[title]` is affected.

It's just a small plugin, but if there is a new version and my client wll update this plugin the changes will be lost.

My question is what in the plugin should I change so the update will be not possible and plugin not recognized?

Will be changing the name enough?

E.g. from:
`Plugin Name: WP jQuery qTip`

to som thing like:
`Plugin Name: WP jQuery qTip - No Update`

?

Or I need to make additional changes in the plugin too?

Comment: Change the name of the plugin to something entirely different, and rename the subdirectory it resides in.

Comment: Or bump the version to something like `9.9.9`.

Comment: @RRikesh Thanks, that's original solution to the problem, thanks for the idea.

Comment: But without the update, if your plugin has full of security holes (risk of hacking), you won't get fixes in future. You have to fix 'em all by yourself.

Comment: @MayeenulIslam you are right, but this is just some jquery stuff to show title attribute in a more fashionable way. Btw. some WP plugins aren't updated for more than 2 years ;). Anyway, you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not modify Themes or Plugins that you don't control. Instead, use one of two options:

1. Patch the Theme/Plugin, and submit the patch to the developer
2. Fork the Theme/Plugin

It sounds like you've opted for option #2. In that case, I would recommend changing both of the following:

1. Update the entire header phpDoc refs to your forked version of the Plugin
2. Change the directory name from `/wp-content/plugins/{plugin-name}`, to `/wp-content/plugins/{forked-plugin-name}`

I believe the bare-minimum change needed is changing the `Plugin name` phpDoc, and the Plugin's directory name.